# How can I draw color blocks in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have extracted colors from an image.
And then I want to show the color and color name beneath the image like this picture.

[image]

But I don't know how to draw color blocks. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ready Matlab function for drawing that kind of color blocks.
You can draw it with few lines of code.

- Use [plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) function for drawing the squares (as graph markers).
- Use [text](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) function for drawing the text.
- Use [dec2hex](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hex2dec.html) for converting each two hex digits to Red Green and Blue color value.

I deliberately kept the code simple (with no loops, arrays and structures):

```
%Read image from imgur hosting sight
I = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Hlh.jpg');

figure, imshow(I), hold on

%x1, y1 - center coordinate of upper square.
x1 = 150;
y1 = 330;
text1 = '#684630'; %Color as hex string.

%Convert hex string to RGB triple.
color1 = hex2dec([text1(2:3); text1(4:5); text1(6:7)]);

x2 = x1;
y2 = y1+25;
text2 = '#211310';
color2 = hex2dec([text2(2:3); text2(4:5); text2(6:7)]);

x3 = x2;
y3 = y2+25;
text3 = '#b2b0ae';
color3 = hex2dec([text3(2:3); text3(4:5); text3(6:7)]);

%Plot squares as markers
plot(x1, y1, 'square', 'MarkerSize', 15, 'MarkerEdgeColor', color1/255, 'MarkerFaceColor', color1/255);
plot(x2, y2, 'square', 'MarkerSize', 15, 'MarkerEdgeColor', color2/255, 'MarkerFaceColor', color2/255);
plot(x3, y3, 'square', 'MarkerSize', 15, 'MarkerEdgeColor', color3/255, 'MarkerFaceColor', color3/255);

%Plot text
text(x1+20, y1, text1, 'FontSize', 12, 'FontName', 'Courier New', 'FontWeight', 'bold');
text(x2+20, y2, text2, 'FontSize', 12, 'FontName', 'Courier New', 'FontWeight', 'bold');
text(x3+20, y3, text3, 'FontSize', 12, 'FontName', 'Courier New', 'FontWeight', 'bold');
```

Result:
[image]